# I'm returning variables to my Flask View but I want to display it without the brackets or single quotes

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

My HTML is formatted as follows:

index.html

```
{% block form_action %}

<form action = "/login" method = "post">
    <p>First Name:</p>
    <p><input type = "text" name = "fnm" /></p>
    <p>Last Name:</p>
    <p><input type = "text" name = "lnm" /></p>

    <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
 </form>

{% endblock form_action %}
```

contact.html

```
{% block form_action %}

<p>Entered Name:</p>
<p> {{ last_name, user_name}} </p>


{% endblock form_action %}
```

python function :

```
@app.route('/login',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():

if request.method ==  'POST':
    fnm = request.form['fnm']  #first name
    lnm = request.form['lnm']
    return render_template('contact.html',user_name = fnm,last_name = lnm)
```

Which outputs the drop down as shown - I would love to display it without the brackets/quotes - Any help is much appreciated.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKeA5.png)

Comment: I think you want `{{last_name}}, {{user_name}}` in your template - in other words, two separate substitutions of strings, rather than a single substitution of a tuple.

Comment: Btw, I imagine your 2nd .html is `contact.html`, not `view.html` .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's answer here what i come up with

Contact.html

```
 {% block form_action %}

 <p>Entered Name:</p>
 <p> {{ last_name}} {{user_name}} </p>


 {% endblock form_action %}
```

Here I changed {{last_name}}, {{user_name}} in template - in other words, two separate substitutions of strings, rather than a single substitution of a tuple {{last_name,user_name}}